# Where to put custom classes to make them globally available to Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class that I'm trying to use in my controller in the index action.

To simplify it, it looks like this

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @front_page = FrontPage.new
  end
end
```

`FrontPage` is a class that I have defined. To include it, I have placed it in the /lib/ folder. I've attempted to `require 'FrontPage'`, `require 'FrontPage.rb'`, `require 'front_page'`, and each of those with the path prepended, eg `require_relative '../../lib/FrontPage.rb'`

I keep getting one of the following messages: `cannot load such file -- /Users/josh/src/ruby/rails/HNReader/lib/front_page` or 
`uninitialized constant PagesController::FrontPage`

Where do I put this file/how do I include it into a controller so that I can instantiate an object?

This is Rails 3.1.3, Ruby 1.9.2, OS X Lion

Comment: Have you tried `require 'front_page'`?

Comment: @Mischa Yes, all of those require arguments should be wrapped in quotes. Thanks for pointing that out. Using that `require` results in the error `cannot load such file -- front_page`

Answer (score 27):

You should be able to use `require 'front_page'` if you are placing `front_page.rb` somewhere in your load path. I.e.: this *should* work:

```
require 'front_page'
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @front_page = FrontPage.new
  end
end
```

To check your load path, try this:

```
$ rails console
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :001 > puts $:
/Users/scottwb/src/my_app/lib
/Users/scottwb/src/my_app/vendor
/Users/scottwb/src/my_app/app/controllers
/Users/scottwb/src/my_app/app/helpers
/Users/scottwb/src/my_app/app/mailers
/Users/scottwb/src/my_app/app/models
/Users/scottwb/src/my_app/app/stylesheets
# ...truncated...
```

You can see in this example, the first line is the project's `lib` directory, which is where you said your `front_page.rb` lives.

Another thing you can do is add this in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

That should make it so you don't even need the `require`; instead Rails will autoload it then (and everything else in your `lib` dir, so be careful).

Comment: autoloading is the key

Comment: thanks you - question: is it dangerous or risky to autoload *everything* in the lib dir?

Answer (score 7):

The file was named `FrontPage.rb`. Changing the name to 'front_page.rb', but leaving the class name as 'FrontPage' resolved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

We just need to load the file,

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  require 'front_page.rb'
  def index
    @front_page = FrontPage.new
  end
end
```

lib/front_page.rb

```
class FrontPage
end
```

We can also set the `application.rb` to **autoload** these files

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
```

Second option would be a preferable solution.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I put it outside the class definition, but checking now, putting it inside the class definition still yields `cannot load such file -- front_page.rb`